# Как в apk приложения попали куски GMS?

Tags: android, apk, google-services

Уже не раз нахожу в apk сторонних приложений куски кода Google Mobile Services (GMS). Кто нибудь знает как они попадают в apk? В каких-то случаях это происходит автоматически или авторы приложений делают это целенаправленно? У меня при сборке в apk таких кусков GMS никогда не добавлялось, поэтому возник вопрос как это может происходить.

[image: Куски GMS в apk]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно как и что вы делаете. Если вы декомпилируете какие-то приложения, то, видимо, наблюдаете результат подключение библиотек от гугла. Их подключают почти все разработчики почти всех приложений для аналитики, пушей, авторизации и прочего.

Comment: Я не знаток Android. Просто считал, что всегда используются Google Services, установленные в системе. А здесь получается приложение таскает все нужные куски кода с собой и ему не нужен установленный apk Google Services в системе?

Comment: Эти куски кода действительно необходимы, но недостаточны для использования GMS. Спасибо, @ЮрийСПб!